# Can't ionic cordova run ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been trying to resolve an issue deploying my app to an ios device for several months to no avail.  I can deploy to Android with no issues but not and iOS device.

One thing I noticed is when I created a new app I can deploy to iOS until I implement facebook authentication.    At any rate, here is the below error message when I try to deploy to an iOS device by plugging the phone into my MAC and running '`ionic cordova run ios`'.

> (node:2643) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection (rejection id: 1): Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild
> with args:
> -xcconfig,/Users/laroca/Development/Mundo/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Mundo.xcworkspace,-scheme,Mundo,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Mundo.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/laroca/Development/Mundo/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/laroca/Development/Mundo/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>
> (node:2643) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
> are deprecated.

In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just running `ionic cordova build ios` (i.e. `build` not `run`)?  I've personally had issues using Ionic's CLI to run directly on a device in 1 step.  So I run the build command (above), then open the XCode project that is created and run on the device via XCode.

Comment: I tried that just now and the run dialog just keeps spinning indefinitely.  It says, "iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone.  xcode will continue when iphone is finished.  No idea what that means

Comment: That actually worked.  I restarted xCode and the iPhone and was able to install the app on an iPhone via xCode.

Comment: Is there a way to use live-reload when you run it on a device through xCode? Using command line (ionic cordova run ios --device -l), you can see changes very quickly on the device. I'm having trouble getting it onto the device through the command line. I can do it through xCode, but really miss the live-reload.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. this link works for me. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3640

To sum up, you must use XCode Legacy build System to build ios At the time I this comment.

Try this.

> XCode > File > Workspace Settings > Build System change to Legacy Build System

Then command to your terminal.

> ionic cordova build ios.

I think it works for you too surely.